# Multilayer Donut Chart for Independent Groups in R

Tags: r, plot, visualization, pie-chart, donut-chart

I saw a picture of a chart below and would like to recreate something similar. My code is below, how would I got about creating a multi-layer donut plot that shows me the percentage of each group?

[image]

```
data <- data.frame(Specialty = c("Neuro-oncologist", "Neurosurgeon", "Radiation-oncologist"),Percentage = c(44.2, 69.6, 17.2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely there is a better way to do it, but if you separate your data in three independent dataframes, show the three dataset in stacked bars and finally change coordinates to polar can get this:

[image]

**Code**:

```
data1 <- data.frame(Specialty = c("Neuro-oncologist", ""),Percentage = c(44.2, 100-44.2))
data2 <- data.frame(Specialty = c("Neurosurgeon", ""),Percentage = c(69.6, 100-69.6))
data3 <- data.frame(Specialty = c("Radiation-oncologist", ""),Percentage = c(17.2, 100-17.2))
  
plt <- ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x = 2, y = Percentage, fill = Specialty), 
                           data = data1, color = "white") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Percentage, x= 2, y = Percentage), data = data1, size = 3) +
  geom_col(aes(x = 3, y = Percentage, fill = Specialty), 
           data = data2, color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Percentage, x= 3, y = Percentage), data = data2, size = 3) +
  geom_col(aes(x = 4, y = Percentage, fill = Specialty), 
           data = data3, color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Percentage, x= 4, y = Percentage), data = data3, size = 3) +
  xlim(0, 4.5) + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank())

plt + coord_polar(theta = "y")
```